# Coin distribution exercise - is it NP-Complete?

Tags: algorithm, np

I want to know if the following problem is NP-Complete or if there's a specific algorithm that solves it:

Imagine you have a certain amount of money, 30€ for example, in coins and bills of specific values (0.01€, 0.05€, 5.00€...).

The quantity of the coins and bills we have is given and you have to distribute it amongst some people **A**, **B**, **C**, etc.

You want **A** to have a certain amount of money (10€, for example), B to have a different or equal amount, and so on.

The sum of the "demanded" money is not greater than the money we have.

So, the question is: `is there a distribution of coins and bills such that every person has the quantity of money that belongs to him?`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds a lot like the Binary Knapsack problem.

Answer (score 5):

One can reduce instances of this problem to Bin Packing (by having A=B=C=...) or to Knapsack (by having only A and B, with B=total-A). Both Bin Packing and Knapsack are known to be NP-complete.